# Dynamic sql insert into returns 'invalid column name'

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I'm trying my first dynamic sql stored procedure. I need to append the exact same records into multiple tables with the same column names. What I have compiles, but when it runs I get 'invalid column name 'TradeDate. The driver sproc is first below, then the sproc containing the dynamic statement. If anyone could help, that'd be great..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2

AS

DECLARE @tableName varchar(120)
SET @tableName = 'tblDailyATR'
EXEC sprocAddDatesAndSymbolsToAggregatedStudy @tableName

RETURN

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sprocAddDatesAndSymbolsToAggregatedStudy
    @table varchar(120)

AS

DECLARE @tableName varchar(120)
SET @tableName = @table

EXEC(
'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '(Symbol, TradeDate)
SELECT Symbol, TradingDate
FROM (SELECT tblSymbolsMain.Symbol, tblTradingDays.TradingDate
      FROM tblSymbolsMain CROSS JOIN tblTradingDays
      WHERE (tblTradingDays.TradingDate <= dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDate())) AS T1
      WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT TradeDate, Symbol
      FROM' + @tableName +
      ' WHERE (TradeDate = T1.TradingDate) AND (Symbol = T1.Symbol)))')

RETURN
```

Comment: regarding the insert, i dont know what your tables look like, but is it possible that they have 'TradingDate' instead of 'TradeDate'?

Comment: As always with dynamic sql, output to a variable, paste it into SSMS, and debug there.

Comment: Use `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';` then assign your SQL to it. When it looks happy via `PRINT` then pass it to `EXEC sp_executesql`, not `EXEC();` - here's why: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx

Comment: @peroija Thanks, that's the first thing I checked, column names are all good..

Comment: @JNK Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep SSMS in mind for the next debug.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the link to your post.. I was reading one yesterday also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space after the "FROM" in this line:

```
FROM' + @tableName +
```

Should be

```
FROM ' + @tableName +
```

Otherwise it's going to try running SELECT FROMTABLE.

Comment: Thanks. That did it... and I swear I checked for such a thing. :)

Comment: @StatsViaCsh before `EXEC();` You should do `PRINT();` by this you can verify your dynamic query..